# JavaScript chaining many function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Newbe in JavaScript, 
I've 4 function say :

```
function funct1(){
    //dosomething();
}

function funct2(){
    //dosomething();
}

function funct3(){
    //dosomething();
}

function funct4(){
    //dosomething();
}
```

I want to exécute funct1 THEN funct2 and funct3. 
But I do want funct4 to be executed ONLY after funct2 AND funct3 have finished ! 
How can'I achieve this, I guess there is a better way to do this ??

I've try this but not very sure of what is running

```
function foo(callback){
    funct1;
    funct2;
    funct3;
    callback();
}

function bar(){
    foo(funct4);
}
```

Comment: this will do what you want except you need `()`s after funct1,2,3 so they are actually executed: `funct1(); funct2(); funct3(); callback();`

Comment: It depends on what `dosomething()` is. Is it something asynchronous?

Comment: I'm not sure if you know what exactly you want to ask.  This sounds like it could be an interesting question.  It isn't yet.  Maybe you could give a few real examples of what you'er planning to do, where you encounter the problem you 're asking about

Comment: All the function are async and some call $Ajax

Comment: Emmanuel Delay, thank you
I'm drawing a dashboard, and at somme point need to draw data brings up with $Ajax by funct4 with data filled by funct2 & funct4. 
I've encoutered erreor due to async execution, that's why I want to be sure that func2 & funct 3 have terminated before executing func4. 
Dont' know if it's more clear !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one (or all) of your functions is async, given that you've tagged your question with jQuery, you can just use promises.

```
function funct1(){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    //Inside some async function, eventually:
    dfd.resolve();
    //More code
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

You can then daisy chain your functions together as shown in the answer by Victor.
If you need to wait for multiple promises to finish (and run multiple in parallel), you can use

```
$.when(funct1, funct2).done(function (arg1, arg2) {
});
```

Comment: Yes, all the functions are async

Comment: Nit, this seems to be what I'm looking for. 
I'm going to try it !

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by following:

```
$.when(funct1).then(funct2).then(funct3).then(funct4)
```

jQuery has own realization of promises, please take a look at documentation or nice tutorials like that http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jquery/deferred-objects.html